# In which section of memory C language variable names are stored?

Tags: c

In which section of memory C language variable names are stored? For example Var_Name is variable name. I want to know where this Var_Name is stored in memory section(code, dat seg etc.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not stored anywhere. Variable names are just labels for the compiler that have no meaning in the binary code hence they are omitted and replaced by relevant memory addresses/registers.

Answer (score 6):

Variable *names* tend to be stored *nowhere* in the in-memory image. The names may exist in the executable file if you have debugging enabled but they're not really necessary for the code to run, hence they're almost invariably not loaded into the process memory.

At the point where the code needs to run, variable names have been replaced by variable addresses (absolute, or relative to some known location, or stack-relative).

They may be loaded into memory for a *different* process, such as if you're using a debugger, but that doesn't make them accessible to the application being debugged.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your object file format.  In most cases, the names are discarded.  A notable exception is if a symbol is exported, as in a shared library or DLL.

Comment: But then thez still arent stored in the memory, since they are stored in the DLL file in this case ;)

Comment: @Zaibis - No, it is usually mapped to memory. Otherwise `dlsym` or `GetProcAddress` would need to peek back at the original file which is kind of ugly.

Comment: And at this time even the identifiers name is loaded in to the memory, and not a representing adress? are you sure about that?

Comment: @Zaibis - Yes I am sure. Look at memory dumps in a debugger to see this.

Comment: Debugging is a another case, in debugging ofcourse the variable names get stored, but in non debug versions i cant imagine that they will be stored in memory, because there is no need for, is it?!

Comment: @Zaibis No, I mean debugging without symbols. For Windows take windbg on notepad.exe or any random process for which you have no source, find the base address of some system DLL and do 'db' until you see the export strings. Or if you like you can disassemble GetProcAddress, you will see that it dereferences the HMODULE as a pointer and does a binary search on the export table, no direct file I/O is involved because the export names are mapped into memory when the module is loaded.

Comment: Ok, you got me. +1 for that from me so far! I recide my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

There are no variable names stored in C. When you create a C file and compile them, it goes through mainly 4 stages (pre-processing, Compilation, Assembly, Linking). These stages essentially convert your code into the language the machine understands when you execute the executable file. These stages replace your names by addresses which the machine understands.

Answer (score 0):

In case of C this names are called "Identifiers" they are mentioned in the standard (and as their name says to identify your variables in the code).

Your compiler needs the identifiers in your code to get the reference where you are handling which variable. But after compilation there is just assembler code (as far you'r not in debug mode). This so called objectfile contains simply said only values (as integer values, instructions or functions) and adresses, which the isntructiosn are interacting with.

So after compilation there is no need of identifiers anymore.
At least not if the user doesn't explicitly needs them. (What would be the case for debuging mode as it already got mentioned before.